# BigQuery & Firebase - Select multiple param values for same event

Tags: android, firebase, google-bigquery, analytics, firebase-analytics

In my android app, I'm logging the number of items selected by the user and the associated price as the following :

```
public static void trackItemsSelectedCount(Context context, int count, int price) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("count", count);
    bundle.putInt("price", price);
    getAnalytics(context).logEvent("items_selected", bundle);
}
```

In BigQuery, I'm able to get the field `price` of the entries having the event `items_selected`, as following :

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT params.value.int_value FROM x.params 
                             WHERE params.key = 'price') AS price
FROM package_ANDROID.app_events_20170123, UNNEST(event_dim) AS x
WHERE x.name  = 'items_selected'
order by price desc
```

However, when I try to get both fields (`price` and `count`) on the same event `items_selected`, the result seems to be inconsistent...

Here is my query that returns inconsistent result :

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT params.value.int_value FROM x.params 
                             WHERE params.key = 'price') AS price,
  (SELECT params.value.int_value FROM x.params 
                             WHERE params.key = 'count') AS count
FROM package_ANDROID.app_events_20170123, UNNEST(event_dim) AS x
WHERE x.name  = 'items_selected'
order by price desc
```

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by inconsistent? What data are you getting back, and what were you expecting to see?

Comment: it's like I am getting mixed values, inconsistent regarding the business association within the app (count vs price) that I can not describe here. But can you tell me if the previous query is correct ? I mean for a given event, I want the related prive and count param. Thx